# replace default image path with custome image path

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

All i really want to do is replace google's path with mine.

//code from module

```
$today = &$handler->current_conditions;
$condition = (string) $today->condition->attributes()->data;

$unit = google_weather_get_unit($convert_to);

$icon_src = (string) $today->icon->attributes()->data;
$content['current'] = array(
    'temp' => $convert_to == 'SI' ? (string) $today->temp_c->attributes()->data . $unit : (string) $today->temp_f->attributes()->data . $unit,
    'humidity' => (string) $today->humidity->attributes()->data,
    'icon' => theme('image', 'http://www.google.com' . $icon_src, $condition, $condition, NULL, FALSE),
    'condition' => $condition,
    'wind_condition' => (string) $today->wind_condition->attributes()->data,
    'custompath'=> $icon_src,
);
```

//code from tpl.php

```
<div class="weather-icon float-left">
   // <?php print $content['current']['icon']; ?>
     <?php print $base_url; ?>
     <?php print $content['current']['custompath']; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you just use a str_replace? For example if it now says http://www.google.com/images/icon.png and you need http://www.myhost.com/images/icon.png:

```
<?php print str_replace("www.google.com", "www.myhost.com", $content['current']['icon']); ?>
```

Comment: str_replace sounds cool but their path is different from mine..say theirs is /weather/ig/images and mine is something else entirely? thats what i really need to do..thanks

Comment: You can use it with entirely different paths if you want:  `str_replace("http://www.google.com/weather/ig/images/", "http://www.mysite.com/another/structure/images/", $content['current']['icon']);` so it's not just the domain you can change, you can change the whole directory structure aswell, they don't have to match up. It just searches for the first string and replaces it with the second one given. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php